# Why won't my timer increment the number?

Tags: javascript

I recently learned javascript. I was experimenting with it. Now, I tried to make a simple timer. Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function start(obj)
    {
        var t = setTimeout("increment(obj)", 1000);
    }

    function increment(obj)
    {
        obj.innerHTML = parseInt(obj.innerHTML) + 1;
        start(obj);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>

<p onclick="start(this)">0</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The contents of the `<p></p>` should be incremented by 1 every second. Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Comment: You will need `setInterval`, not `setTimeout` btw.

Comment: @fk82 he is calling start again so setTimeout is just fine in this scenario..

Comment: @Gaby: It's ambiguous. The code would do that; but actually I think the intention is `"(...) contents of the <p></p> should be incremented by 1 every second."` :-) Which ofc would not happen unless the user clicks precisely every second.

Comment: @FK82, not it is not.. it is a loop happening each time the `start` gets fired.  first time is through the click, but then it takes a life of its own since each timeout re-calls the `start` method which starts a new timeout ..

Comment: @Gaby: Ok, I did not see the `start(obj)` the first time around. It does not matter however, using `setInterval` upon click would be the simpler way to do this.

Comment: @FK82, no argument there :) I agree completely..

Comment: @Gaby: And we've reached a verdict. Good talking to you :-)

Comment: @Agadoo: Did any of the answers here help you? If so, please accept the best one.

Answer (score 5):

Because the string you pass into `setTimeout` is evaluated at *global* scope, not the scope within the function, and so doesn't refer to your `obj` object.

You should never pass strings to `setTimeout`. Instead, pass it a function reference:

```
function start(obj)
{
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
                increment(obj);
            }, 1000);
}

function increment(obj)
{
    obj.innerHTML = parseInt(obj.innerHTML) + 1;
    start(obj);
}
```

The function we're passing to `setTimeout` is a closure, which means it has an enduring reference to the items in scope where it's defined. So a second later when the timer mechanism calls it, it still has access to the `obj` argument of your `start` function even though the `start` function has long since returned. More here: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Answer (score 2):

The issue (or at least, the first that I see) is that you are passing the string "increment(obj)" to the `setTimeout()` method, but `obj` is only defined inside of your `start()` method.  The string that you pass isn't actually evaluated until the timeout triggers, at which point no `obj` variable is in scope.

There are a few different ways around this.  One is to pass a closure to `setTimeout()` instead of a JavaScript string, like:

```
function start(obj) {
    var nextIncrement = function() {
        increment(obj);
    };
    var t = setTimeout(nextIncrement, 1000);
}
```

Another (though less preferable) option is to promote `obj` to the global scope, like:

```
function start(obj) {
    window.obj = obj;
    var t = setTimeout("increment(obj)", 1000);
}
```

In general, however, you should avoid passing a string to `setTimeout` (and you should also avoid placing things in the global scope unnecessarily).  As you have seen, it can cause issues with scope resolution, and for any non-trivial operation it also makes you code much less maintainable.  Always prefer passing a function closure when possible.

Also, the following line of code is [probably not doing exactly what you expect](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/394):

```
parseInt(obj.innerHTML)
```

You should always provide the radix argument to `parseInt`, to avoid errors with values such as `011` (which is 9, rather than 11, because it is evaluated in base-8 due to the leading `0`).  You can avoid these quirks by simply doing:

```
parseInt(obj.innerHTML, 10)
```

...to force a base-10 parse.

Anyways, working example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/dSLZG/1

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line of code:

```
    var t = setTimeout("increment(obj)", 1000);
```

`obj` is an identifier in the functions scope -- it is only accessible within the `start` function.  When you pass a string to `setTimeout`, it is evaluated in the global scope.  This means that the `obj` variable is not available, so nothing is incremented.

You should pass a function object instead, as this will create a closure and your variable will be accessible:

```
function start(obj)
{
    setTimeout(function() {
        increment(obj);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Note that I have removed the unnecessary `var t =`, because you're not doing anything with the timer identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I've copied your code over to jsFidle and added a working example. See [sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/FLJ47/).
The problem in your original version is that your variable obj is not defined in the global context. Whenever you pass strings to `setTimeout` you'll end up having the string evaluated in the global context (where `obj` is not a variable).

What you should do instead is never pass a string to `setTimeout` but a function object. This function object holds references to all variables that are set where the function object was defined.
So, because the function object passed to `setTimeout` in `start2` is defined within `start2` it has access to all variables and parameters of `start2`. Your variable `obj` is one of those and thus accessible within the function object as soon as it is executed by `setTimeout`.